# How to set a breakpoint on a channel read/write

Tags: go, delve

I'm trying to understand behaviour of a Go program, so I'm running it in a debugger (delve). I can trace the execution flow easily, until it hits a loop which sends data to a channel.

I'm trying to figure out what code is reading from the channel, i.e. what will be executed once the write happens. Is it possible to figure out? Is it possible to set a breakpoint on read from that channel?

I tried inspecting the channel's internals (`hchan`) in debugger. I can see it has a `recvq` and `sendq` fields, which point to a `runtime.sudog` and `runtime.g` structs with some runtime internals including a `pc` or Program Counter. However, from that I can't figure out where is the code is.

Comment: The `g` is a goroutine. However, there may not be anyone actually reading the channel at the time your goroutine *writes* to the channel. You're probably better off setting a breakpoint in whichever goroutine is-or-will-be reading from the channel, at or near the line of code that contains a request to read from the channel.

Comment: That's the problem I'm trying to solve - figuring out which goroutine will be reading from the channel. The code is too complex to figure it out reasonably quickly.

Comment: The problem is not solveable in general: if the channel is buffered, perhaps *no* goroutine is trying to read from it right now. If it's unbuffered, the channel-send operation will block unless it's a nonblocking send (part of a select) and you could see which goroutine(s) are the reason it isn't blocking, but if there is more than one, there's no guarantee that one *specific* one of these blocked goroutines is the one that will wind up unblocked as a result. (The actual code, IIRC, will use a wakeup or notewakeup and it's the wakeup that will reschedule the sleeper[s].)